# Вложенные циклы JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть простая задача по выводу простых чисел. Вот код:

```
`nextPrime:
for (let i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
  }

  alert( i );
}`
```

Код полностью рабочий. Хочу понять, почему j во вложенном цикле сбрасывается, при увеличении i

Comment: А что должно произойти? У Вас при первой же проверке остаток от деления  равен 0 и переход на **nextPrime**, что приводит новому циклу по **i** и **j**. Замените **continue nextPrime;** на **continue;**

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли вопрос. Если i к примеры уже равен 6, то j перед этим, уже увеличивался несколько раз (в зависимости от i). Но когда i вновь увеличивается, j сбрасывается снова на 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что внутри первого цикла ты целиком определил второй цикл. Так и должно быть.
Вот если бы j зависело от i или инициализировалось раньше тогда могло бы быть иначе.

Например вот второй случай, когда инициализация innerCounter делается до внешнего цикла:

```
let innerCounter = 0

for(let outerCounter = 0; outerCounter < 11; outerCounter++){
  for(;innerCounter<outerCounter*10 + 1;innerCounter++){
    console.log([outerCounter, innerCounter]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Понял. Благодарю!